# How to sort alphanumeric parameter/field in SSRS 2016 correctly?

Tags: sql, sorting, alphanumeric, ssrs-2016

I have a report for inventory that needs to be fixed.  We have parameters of beginning bins and ending bins.  Right now, the parameters are sorting the bins like A1, A10, A11, A12, A2, A20, A21, A3 etc.

I realize the mistake was not putting in a "0" before A2, A3 etc.  I am trying to figure out how to sort this correctly so it displays A1, A2, A3 before A10, A11, A12...

I am not sure if the best way to go about this is with a tablix properties sort expression or casting it in my dataset query? Any help is appreciated.

```sql
    WHERE        
    (p21_view_location.location_id = @Location_ID) 
    AND (p21_view_inv_loc.qty_on_hand >= @Minimum_QOH)
    --AND bins.[QOH (Bin)] >= @Minimum_QOH
    AND (bins.bin BETWEEN @Beginning_Bin_No AND @Ending_Bin_No OR bins.Bin is null)
    AND p21_view_inv_mast.item_id NOT LIKE '%FEE%'
    AND p21_view_item_uom.delete_flag <> 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help...

```
with t (afield) as
(SELECT 'a10' UNION
SELECT 'a1' UNION
SELECT 'a2' )
select afield, substring(afield,1,1) aletter, CAST(substring(afield,2,len(afield)) as int) anumber from t
order by aletter, anumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select cast(replace('A10', 'A', '') as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above query,

1. replace first character as empty string ' ' of your bin value in table and bin parameter value. Then compare both in where clause.

```
 WHERE        
    (p21_view_location.location_id = @Location_ID) 
    AND (p21_view_inv_loc.qty_on_hand >= @Minimum_QOH)
    --AND bins.[QOH (Bin)] >= @Minimum_QOH
    AND ((cast(stuff(bins.bin,1,1,'') as int) BETWEEN cast(stuff(@Beginning_Bin_No,1,1,'') as int) AND cast(stuff(@Ending_Bin_No,1,1,'') as int)) OR bins.Bin is null)
    AND p21_view_inv_mast.item_id NOT LIKE '%FEE%'
    AND p21_view_item_uom.delete_flag <> 'Y'
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'E2' to data type int.  I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Above query will work fine. Please mention your full query and sample record details for further clarification.